# Average Row Duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataset with duplicate row names but different values and I need to average them but have not been able to. 
My table is similar as following

```
Genes S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6
EST01 0  1  5  7  0  0
EST01 1  1  0  9  2  0
EST05 8  0  1  0  1  3
EST70 4  3  0  0  0  0
EST05 5  1  3  6  0  3
EST11 6  8  0  2  0  3
EST01 4  0  2  4  5  1
```

I need to get an average for all columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 corresponding to the duplicated rows in the Genes column.

I followed a code from StackOverflow:

```
head(Gene_IDs)
keys <- colnames(Gene_IDs)[!grepl('1', colnames(Gene_IDs))]
X <- as.data.table(Gene_IDs)
X[,list(mm= mean(1)),keys]
X[,lapply(.SD,mean),keys] -> agg
head(agg)
```

But my final table still contains the duplicates and I am not sure what to do.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Were you aware that this code is clearly from a source that is using the `data.table` package? If so you should have included `library(data.table)` and the code to create that data object.

Comment: Check if your `keys` contains the expected columns (Genes?), and if not, construct it a different way..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make this a reproducible example (e.g. so we don't have to create your data structures) and also provide an example of what your code is producing and what you would ideally like to see as output. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating.
All you need to do is get mean across all the columns based on the group genes.

datatable way

```
df[ ,lapply(.SD, mean), by = Genes]
```

base R

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(lapply(split(df,df$Genes),`[`,2:ncol(df)),colMeans))
```